# Shiny app that allows user to click in several images in a grid and capture the clicked values

Tags: r, image, shiny

I want to create a shiny app that shows several images (in a grid) of people to the user, and then the user will click in all images that show the same person (a sort of manual facial recognition). I need to have access to these clicked values.

The idea is to have something like this image picker:
https://rvera.github.io/image-picker/
(see the Selects Multiple section).

Is this possible in Shiny? The only way I've found was to embed the images in a DT::datatable object, and then select the rows by clicking in it, but in this case there will be only one image per row (and I'd like something more like a grid of images).

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use `actionButton`and include the images with `tags$image` in the label. It could look something like this.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Examples of DataTables",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      actionButton(
        "cat",
        label = tags$image(src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KR9kjuuxRO0/maxresdefault.jpg")
      ),
      textOutput(
        outputId = "result"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # choose columns to display
  output$result <- renderText(
    paste("cat has been clicked", input$cat, "number of times")
  )
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```